# Magento 2 | Deploy static content from only one source

Tags: magento-2.1, error, static-content-deploy

I got some errors when trying to compile where CSS is not being generated for adminhtml.

I got this in the shell:

```
Compilation from source: /microcloud/domains/operm2/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles.less

Compilation from source:
adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
Unable to get content for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Checkout/css/source/_module.less'

..............................................................

Successful: 2662 files; errors: 2
```

When I add **-vvv** the generated result is almost unreadable.

Is it possible to run deploy command only from one source?

e.g.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
```